# How Do I Get the Magento API 2 Product By ID (Not SKU)?

Tags: post, magento, magento2

**Use-case:**

When creating a product, it is my understanding that a key/value pair of `id` is required for all product types for the HTTP POST request into the Magento API Endpoint `/pub/rest/default/V1/products`.

**Issue:**

However, as I've experienced, I can overwrite products when using the same `id`. Thusly, I would like to check whether the `id` exists in Magento before using it.

**Request:**

Which endpoint can I use to query to see whether an `id` exists? Looking at the [Docs](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/quick-reference/) I couldn't see anywhere to support this requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [the docs](https://adobe-commerce.redoc.ly/2.4.5-admin/tag/products/#operation/PostV1Products), an `id` of 0 is used. If an `id` is not provided, it will be created and returned in the response.

The `id` should not be specified for a new product, though, since it's an auto-generated field. Your unique identifier for a product should be `sku`. To confirm that a SKU doesn't exist, you could call https://adobe-commerce.redoc.ly/2.4.5-admin/tag/productssku#operation/GetV1ProductsSku. This endpoint will also return the `id` for the product.

Having a way to uniquely identify your product before adding/updating is pretty important, but if you want to do indiscriminate adds, you can just call that endpoint you reference but either use an `id` of 0 or don't include `id` at all.

Comment: Hi Jessica, thank you for the response. I'll be trying this out today. The problem with seeing whether the SKU exists with this endpoint, is that it returns a 404 error. Using the query parameters is more appropriate, as there is a key/value pair of `total_count`.

Answer (score 1):

Search endpoint can be used to achieve what you need.
Example request URL would look like this:

```
http://localhost/rest/all/V1/products?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=entity_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=<id>
```

Note that the store code (*all*) might differ.

See [Magento docs](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/use-rest/search-endpoint/) for more info.

Comment: Have you ever managed to use this query with oAuth1? The square brackets throw me a 401 error.

Answer (score 0):

[This query](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/use-rest/search-endpoint/) was used to successfully query whether the `product_id`exists

```
http://example.com/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=entity_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=[product_id]
```

Go to the [API Docs](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/quick-reference/): and then to product to learn more.

[image]